# how to upload optional images if not selected in android using volley

Tags: java, android

I have tried many time but no solution found for this issue.
My android app contains 5 upload image buttons but problem is that if user upload less then 5 images on server using volley library in android and PHP then my app throws `NullPointerException`. Please tell me, how can I handle this issue?

Comment: Please post some code to help. You might have to check  `if(yourimage != null){ uploadToServer() }`

Comment: Show us the logcat

Comment: Probably in your app you expects all 5 files to upload, please add kind of validation if `file == null` -> do not try upload. But without src code is hard to help you.

Comment: Yes you can check my source code in the link below.Hope that is enough for you to help me.Thanks  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HfpUwY8Kt53jjPCUr8aAad8KXrGTvZPa